# SQL Advanced SELECT query question

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables, which, among other things contain:

```
CustomerOrder
---
idOrder
TableNumber

OrderStatus
--------
Menu
idMenu
Name

MenuItemOrdered
------------
idMenuItemOrdered
MenuID
OrderID
TableNumber
```

I want to retrieve the following result:

```
Menu.Name CustomerOrder.TableNumber CustomerOrder.OrderStatus
-------------------------------------------------------------
Fish            1               New
Chicken         1               New
Steak           1               New
Steak           2               New
Steak           2               New
Steak           2               New
Steak           2               New
```

I've come up with:

```
SELECT Menu.Name, CustomerOrder.TableNumber, CustomerOrder.OrderStatus 
FROM Menu, CustomerOrder 
WHERE Menu.idMenu IN (SELECT MenuID FROM MenuItemOrdered) 
AND CustomerOrder.OrderStatus = "New" OR CustomerOrder.OrderStatus = "Cooking"
ORDER By CustomerOrder.TableNumber
```

But, I don't feel quite confident on that answer.  Any clues how to pull this off?

Comment: Learning is about trying. Build your tables, put in some sample data, and give it a try!

Comment: I understand that and typically do so.  The sheer amount of data I'd have to put in, in this case, though, in order to even get to the point where I can test this has had me come here for advice before attempting that route.

Comment: It requires three CREATE TABLE statements and an INSERT for each table with a UNION ALL. How is that a "sheer amount of data"?

Comment: I thought I was quite clear on the result I was asking for.  However, that doesn't seem to be the case, so I'll ask here again.  I want to retrieve a table that populates Menu.Name, CustomerOrder.TableNumber, and CustomerOrder.OrderStatus from the three tables I listed.  How do I do so?  Also, this isn't homework. :)

Comment: @Ken - The tables are already created.  However, these are only three tables of a very large database, and in order to not interfere with the other tables, I cannot simply add to the three tables.  I'd have to add to the rest, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT Menu.Name, CustomerOrder.TableNumber, CustomerOrder.OrderStatus 
FROM CustomerOrder
JOIN menuitemordered on customeorder.idorder = menuitemordered.orderid
JOIN menu on menuitemordered.menuid = menu.idmenu
WHERE CustomerOrder.OrderStatus = "New" OR CustomerOrder.OrderStatus = "Cooking"
ORDER By CustomerOrder.TableNumber
```

I think it is really strange that the menu id is called idmenu in one table and menuid in another (this is true of order id too!)

Comment: And then there are people like you that restore my faith in asking others for help when you need it.  Thank you, your solution looks like what I am trying to retrieve!  Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, and on the orderid and menuid thing, MySQL Workbench by default names the primary key by idTableName, which is where idMenu and idCustomerOrder come in.  I, however, am used to doing it the other way and labeling it menuid and customerorderid, but that's more of my prior experience with naming things and probably should change it to MySQL's naming convention.

Comment: In my experience MenuID is the more common form.  But having it both ways def. has a bad smell about it and is confusing.

Comment: I agree.  I wish MySQL Workbench used the other convention by default, but I should definitely change mine to make it less confusing.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @Hogan +1 you beat me to it by a few seconds... =]

Comment: @rsbarro : Sorry about that :(

Comment: I guess I have to register for an account to give you guys, what is it, "rep"?  I am very new to the site and only tend to ask questions when I'm really baffled.  :)

Comment: @Chad Yea, you need to earn like 15 rep I think before you can upvote. Also, whichever answer you like, you can just click the checkbox under it to accept it whenever you're ready.

Comment: Bah, why couldn't I pick both the answers?  :(  I liked both of your answers!

Comment: Hehe, you only get to pick one. They were both essentially the same anyway. =]

Answer (score 0):

I do think it's homework, but in addressing the question as asked, I will simply point out that by giving an incomplete spec of the tables (for example, I am sure there is a CustomerOrder.idCustomer, and a table called 'Table', etc), you leave us in the position of guessing at what should be added to or subtracted from your query.
Somewhere in your textbook, there is a section on joins, which you should review.

Comment: Very few of us "feel confident" about SQL statement selection. It would have been nice to see you tried at least the one you'd already written.